# Are legendary items found in the world a one time item?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

There are some YouTube videos which show the location of certain legendary items in the world, and where to find them.

I found one through exploration and soon out levelled it and ended up selling it. It seems legendary items drop at your current level. I know I can upgrade them, but I do not have any legendary crafting materials just yet.

Once I've collected them are they gone forever?

Comment: You can't upgrade legendary items. I guess you mean iconic items. Those have a blue rarity, although their symbol in the world is bright orange when you loot them. Also yes, their are supposed to be unique, so once gone and you can't re-buy them at the vendor, then you can't get them back.

Comment: Nope, I mean legendary, orange rarity. Iconic are just unique items, which can be of any rarity.

Comment: I'm not convinced they're entirely unique. I've found duplicates of the weapon I'm currently using at higher levels on more than one occasion from weapon vendors. Whether this means that you can find every legendary from vendors I am unsure.

Comment: Iconic are not unique in the game, but a unique named item. Such as Chaos the Maelstrom sidearm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are. Legendary items looted from world caches are a one time deal.

I looted a Legendary Monowire a few days ago.

[image: Legendary monowire]

When I returned to the chest where I found it today, the chest was open.

[image: Empty looted chest]

This would mean that if you do use a YouTube video to loot legendary items from the world they will be dropped at your current level, and you'll outlevel them unless you upgrade them.

Comment: It should be noted though that (I don't think) cyberware such as that Monowire is levelled, and more importantly, the impact of level on armor is pretty negligible - if it's got three/four mod slots, you can craft higher level armadillo mods to replace the ones you had in there every few levels very cheaply and it will make level differences in base armor into pure noise. In the case of iconic weapons, you can hold off on upgrading to epic/legendary until you've outlevelled the current stage to make them last a bit longer. In the case of non-iconic weapons, they aren't unique anyway, so go HAM